# How to make a controll stick to its parent borders on resize?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have a `TGroupBox` as a parent and i want to place a button inside it, and make it so the button would stick to the top right corner of groupbox.

The problem is, `TGroupBox` does not have the method `OnResize`, so i don't know how to tell a button where should it move after groupbox was resized.

Is there any way to make it happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the button's [`Anchors`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.Anchors) property to include `akTop` and `akRight`. When its parent's size changes, it will move to keep its top and right offsets constant relative to the edges of the parent control. The default value has `akLeft` instead. (If both `akLeft` and `akRight` are set, then the button's width will grow and shrink with its parent.)

Between the [`Align`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.Align), [`Anchors`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.Anchors), and [`Constraints`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.Constraints) properties, you will rarely have to write any of your own code to handle changes to a parent's size.

Comment: Thank you. Such a simple thing, and i have never taken a look at this property before :)

Answer (score 3):

Place it in correct place and change his properties Anchor.akLeft to false and Anchor.akRight to true. No need to attach to any events.

So Anchor will be:

```
.akTop = true
.akLeft = false
.akBottom = false
.akRight = true
```

(properties of button inside groupbox)